# install PyQt4 on mac error

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm getting this error on the `make install` part of the installation process.

```
ld: library not found for -lqpycore
```

Not sure what this means.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the library `qpycore` is not installed, maybe you have missed some dependency?

Answer (score 9):

I got this same error trying to install pyqt5 on Mac OS 10.8.  The solution for me was to cd into the qpy directory (under the PyQt-gpl install directory) and make.  Once finished cd .., and sudo make install again.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked for me on OSX 10.6.8 and PyQt4.10.2 Would be good if someone knew enough about the build mechanism to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

For me, first `make` then `make install` worked as well.